# RobotFramework: Can not leave the error message if the element is not exist

Tags: python, selenium, wait, robotframework

robotFramework test cases:

```
verify that user can send a request and redirect to next page
    Wait until element is enabled    ${errorCodeMessage}
    Element Text Should Be    ${errorCodeMessage}    Vikailmoituksen tapahtumat
```

output logs:

```
Send request with 'Proprietary Tag' field :: OK: User is able to s... | FAIL |
Element locator '//h2' did not match any elements after 5 seconds
```

How can I return the error message(example: "There is no such element at this page") when element is not exist?
Instead of this: `"Element locator '//h2' did not match any elements after 5 seconds"`

Comment: I don't know the robotFramework but typically you would use a try/catch to trap the NoSuchElement exception and write a custom message to the log.

Comment: @JeffC: that's not how you do it in robotframework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation, [wait until element is enabled](http://robotframework.org/Selenium2Library/doc/Selenium2Library.html#Wait%20Until%20Element%20Is%20Enabled) accepts an error message as an argument. So, it would look something like this:

```
Wait until element is enabled    ${errorCodeMessage}
...    error=There is no such element on this page
```